# Postfix Dovecot SASL Authentication not enabled/working ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: server, email, postfix, dovecot, sasl

I set-up Postfix running with Dovecot with SASL support with virtual mailboxes in a Postgresql Database and Amavis Clamav and Spamassassin all working together

Working = I can send and receive email to both internal and external (google) accounts. When the email is received it is stored in virtual mailbox -- /mwdmail/mbox/example.com/test@example.com/

**Not working** - I cannot telnet to port 25 from an external network - i get "connection refused" nor do I see AUTH LOGIN when I succesfully telnet locally to port 25

How do I get Dovecot SASL working?

Below are my settings:

- My router and ufw firewall are open on ports 80, 433, 25, 110, 143, 465, 587, 993 and 995
- The Postfix version is 2.11.0

**postconf - m** (below)

```
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
internal
memcache
nis
pcre
pgsql
proxy
regexp
socketmap
static
tcp
texthash
unix
```

**postconf - a**  = dovecot
**postconf - n** below: -- my domain name has been changed to example.com for privacy

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_original_recipient = no
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
local_transport = virtual
mail_owner = mwdpost
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/local/man
mydestination = example.com, localhost.com, localhost
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf
relayhost =
setgid_group = mwdpdrop
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/controlled_envelope_senders
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_sender_domain, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_alias_map.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:3205
virtual_mailbox_base = /mwdmail/mbox
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_domain_map.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 512000000
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_map.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 3205
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:3205
```

### **Postfix Master.cf** (postconf -M) file =

```
# SMTP on port 25, unencrypted.
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v

smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v

# SMTP with TLS on port 587.
submission inet n - - - - smtpd -v
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/controlled_envelope_senders
# -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

# SMTP over SSL on port 465.
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous

#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache

# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=mwdvm:mwdvm argv=/usr/bin/vendor_perl/spamc -f -e /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

# The next two entries integrate with Amavis for anti-virus/spam checks.
amavis      unix    -       -       -       -       3       smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o max_use=20
127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o local_recipient_maps=
  -o relay_recipient_maps=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
  -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
  -o mynetworks=192.168.0.0/32,127.0.0.0/8
#  -o mynetworks=0.0.0.0
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
#
#
##############
# Integration with Dovecot - hand mail over to it for local delivery, and
# run the process under the vmail user and mail group.
dovecot      unix   -        n      n       -       -   pipe
  flags=DRhu user=mwdvm:mwdvm argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $(recipient)
```

**UPDATE**

- **Anders Klaer - Thanks for the update and tips!**
- **Added smtpd line in master.cf and reloaded postfix**, but when I telnet to port 25 both to localhost and to my internal ip address from another machine on the same network, the AUTH LOGIN (SASL "enabled") code is not there.

**SEE MAIL.LOG below....**

```
Jan 28 07:41:54 example spamd[1860]: spamd: server hit by SIGHUP, restarting
Jan 28 07:41:54 example spamd[1860]: spamd: child [1864] killed successfully: interrupted, signal 2 (0002)
Jan 28 07:41:54 example spamd[1860]: spamd: child [1863] killed successfully: interrupted, signal 2 (0002)
Jan 28 07:41:54 example spamd[1860]: logger: removing stderr method
Jan 28 07:41:54 example postfix/pickup[15760]: C407622208B: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan 28 07:41:55 example postfix/cleanup[16769]: C407622208B: message-id=<20140128124154.C407622208B@example.com>
Jan 28 07:41:55 example postfix/qmgr[2413]: C407622208B: from=<root@example.com>, size=1042, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 28 07:41:55 example postfix/trivial-rewrite[16772]: warning: do not list domain example.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jan 28 07:41:55 example postfix/virtual[16775]: C407622208B: to=<mwdadm@example.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.78, delays=0.54/0.09/0/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan 28 07:41:55 example postfix/qmgr[2413]: C407622208B: removed
Jan 28 07:41:59 example spamd[16768]: spamd: server started on port 783/tcp (running version 3.3.2)
Jan 28 07:41:59 example spamd[16768]: spamd: server pid: 16768
Jan 28 07:41:59 example spamd[16768]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 16780
Jan 28 07:42:00 example spamd[16768]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 16781
Jan 28 07:42:00 example spamd[16768]: prefork: child states: IS
Jan 28 07:42:00 example spamd[16768]: prefork: child states: II
Jan 29 03:21:51 example postfix/postfix-script[26285]: error: unknown command: 'quiet-reload'
Jan 29 03:21:51 example postfix/postfix-script[26286]: fatal: usage: postfix start (or stop, reload, abort, flush, check, status, set-permissions, upgrade-configuration)
Jan 29 03:22:02 example postfix/postfix-script[26298]: refreshing the Postfix mail system
Jan 29 03:22:02 example postfix/master[2411]: reload -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: name_mask: ipv4
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: inet_addr_local: configured 3 IPv4 addresses
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: process generation: 45 (45)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: mynetworks ~? debug_peer_list
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: mynetworks ~? fast_flush_domains
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: mynetworks ~? mynetworks
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: relay_domains ~? debug_peer_list
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: relay_domains ~? fast_flush_domains
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: relay_domains ~? mynetworks
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: relay_domains ~? permit_mx_backup_networks
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: relay_domains ~? qmqpd_authorized_clients
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: relay_domains ~? relay_domains
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: connect to subsystem private/proxymap
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr request = open
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr table = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr flags = 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: flags
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: flags
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 16
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: (end)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: dict_proxy_open: connect to map=pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf status=0 server_flags=fixed
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: dict_open: proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: permit_mx_backup_networks ~? debug_peer_list
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: permit_mx_backup_networks ~? fast_flush_domains
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: permit_mx_backup_networks ~? mynetworks
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: permit_mx_backup_networks ~? permit_mx_backup_networks
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr request = open
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr table = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_map.cf
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr flags = 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: flags
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: flags
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 16
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: (end)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: dict_proxy_open: connect to map=pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_map.cf status=0 server_flags=fixed
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: dict_open: proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_map.cf
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr request = open
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr table = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_alias_map.cf
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr flags = 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: flags
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: flags
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 16
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/proxymap socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: (end)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: dict_proxy_open: connect to map=pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_alias_map.cf status=0 server_flags=fixed
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: dict_open: proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_alias_map.cf
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: smtpd_access_maps ~? debug_peer_list
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: smtpd_access_maps ~? fast_flush_domains
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: smtpd_access_maps ~? mynetworks
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: smtpd_access_maps ~? permit_mx_backup_networks
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: smtpd_access_maps ~? qmqpd_authorized_clients
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: smtpd_access_maps ~? relay_domains
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: smtpd_access_maps ~? smtpd_access_maps
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: Compiled against Berkeley DB: 5.1.25?
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: Run-time linked against Berkeley DB: 5.1.25?
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: dict_open: hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/controlled_envelope_senders
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: unknown_helo_hostname_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: unknown_address_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: unverified_recipient_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: unverified_sender_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: name_mask: 1
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: auto_clnt_create: transport=local endpoint=private/tlsmgr
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/tlsmgr
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr request = seed
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr size = 32
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: seed
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: seed
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: tY2AjIfcnb7dQy7h5HZqAXZra1dZjtiV/wtYGhppqcQ=
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: (end)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr request = policy
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: send attr cache_type = smtpd
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: status
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: cachable
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: cachable
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: timeout
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: timeout
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute value: 3600
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: input attribute name: (end)
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: fast_flush_domains ~? debug_peer_list
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_string: fast_flush_domains ~? fast_flush_domains
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: auto_clnt_create: transport=local endpoint=private/anvil
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: connection established
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: master_notify: status 0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: name_mask: resource
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: name_mask: software
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: connect from example.com[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_list_match: example.com: no match
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_list_match: 127.0.0.1: no match
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_list_match: example.com: no match
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_list_match: 127.0.0.1: no match
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_hostname: example.com ~? 192.168.0.0/24
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_hostaddr: 127.0.0.1 ~? 192.168.0.0/24
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_hostname: example.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_hostaddr: 127.0.0.1 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jan 29 03:22:20 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 220 example.com ESMTP Postfix
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: < example.com[127.0.0.1]: ehlo mwe
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_list_match: example.com: no match
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_list_match: 127.0.0.1: no match
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 250-example.com
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 250-PIPELINING
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 250-SIZE 10240000
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 250-ETRN
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 250-STARTTLS
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 250-8BITMIME
Jan 29 03:22:25 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 250 DSN
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: < example.com[127.0.0.1]: quit
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: > example.com[127.0.0.1]: 221 2.0.0 Bye
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_hostname: example.com ~? 192.168.0.0/24
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_hostaddr: 127.0.0.1 ~? 192.168.0.0/24
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_hostname: example.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: match_hostaddr: 127.0.0.1 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: disconnect from example.com[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: master_notify: status 1
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: connection closed
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: proxymap stream disconnect
Jan 29 03:22:31 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: auto_clnt_close: disconnect private/tlsmgr stream
Jan 29 03:24:11 example postfix/smtpd[26308]: idle timeout -- exiting
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! When you include commands or inputs\outputs from\to commands in your questions, instead of manually trying to format it for readability, paste the output in the editor, mark\highlight it and then click on the $ symbol for formatting it as code. That will make sure your output isn't stripped for newlines and white-spaces. Also feel free to edit your question at any time to add more updates to reflect to the progress of achieving the main questions goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i could see is your master.cf lacking this line.
Put it in your configuration and do a `sudo service postfix reload`

```
# /etc/postfix/master.cf
# Listen on port 25.
smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

[From the postfix manual](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html):

*To offer SASL authentication only after a TLS-encrypted session has been established specify this:*

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

From your `main.cf` is `smtpd_tls_auth_only` set to `yes`.
Update it to `no` and reload Postfix should give you the AUTH.

Comment: Anders, I think by adding the line above i was allowed to connect to port 25 from external networks (meaning before I could only connect on localhost..but now I can connect to port 25 from another internal machine (haven't tried externally yet as working on home network now)).ALSO, there are some "no match" errors in the log which might be a clue to the SASL AUth problem but not sure. All help is appreciated!

Comment: @Cmweb, you may also find this one helpful, https://qmail.jms1.net/test-auth.shtml

Comment: Thanks again Anders....setting "smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes" to "no" worked. I have SASL Auth now ...I need to read-up more because I would like to offer "SASL authentication only after a TLS-encrypted session has been established" as I wish to have this as secure as possible, but I am sure I am missing something in regards to the TLS setup.  At least now it works!   and thank you for the link.  I will do some tests (it seems the options for setting up a mail server a plenteous) to figure out what is the best setup.  For now, happy days  have returned!

Comment: @Cmweb feel free to accept the answer. You can always raise a new question if you run into one. Wish you good luck : )