# Postfix PostgreSQL Dovecot SASL Authentication Fails Ubuntu 14.04LTS Server

Tags: 14.04, postfix, postgresql, dovecot, sasl

I previously setup my mail server using Ubuntu 12.04LTS and all worked fine (see [Postfix Dovecot SASL Authentication not enabled/working ubuntu 12.04 server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411057/postfix-dovecot-sasl-authentication-not-enabled-working-ubuntu-12-04-server)),  but I recently moved everything to new server and upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I lost something in the Dovecot SASL configuration because I can't Authenticate using Dovecot SASL ...  I get the following error

```
Jun 12 05:15:30 example dovecot: auth: Error: pgsql(192.168.1.11:3145): Connect failed to database mwdmail: could not translate host name "192.168.1.11:3145" to address: Name or service not known
Jun 12 05:15:30 example dovecot: auth: Error: pgsql(192.168.1.11:3145): Connect failed to database mwdmail: could not translate host name "192.168.1.11:3145" to address: Name or service not known
Jun 12 05:16:31 example dovecot: auth: Error: pgsql: Query timed out (no free connections for 61 secs): SELECT username as user, password, '/mwdmail/mbox/example.com/cmadm' as userdb_home, 'maildir:/mwdmail/mbox/example.com/cmadm' as userdb_mail, 3205 as userdb_uid, 3205 as userdb_gid FROM mailbox WHERE username='cmadm@example.com' AND active = true;
Jun 12 05:16:31 example dovecot: auth: Error: sql(cmadm@example.com,127.0.0.1,<tYikAKD74gB/AAAB>): Password query failed: Not connected to database
Jun 12 05:17:44 example dovecot: auth: Error: pgsql(192.168.1.11:3145): Connect failed to database mwdmail: could not translate host name "192.168.1.11:3145" to address: Name or service not known
Jun 12 05:17:44 example dovecot: auth: Error: pgsql(192.168.1.11:3145): Connect failed to database mwdmail: could not translate host name "192.168.1.11:3145" to address: Name or service not known
```

### postconf -n (main.cf file)

```
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    append_dot_mydomain = no
    biff = no
    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    command_directory = /usr/sbin
    config_directory = /etc/postfix
    content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
    daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
    data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
    disable_vrfy_command = yes
    dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
    enable_original_recipient = no
    header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
    inet_interfaces = all
    inet_protocols = ipv4
    local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
    local_transport = virtual
    mail_owner = mwdpost
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
    manpage_directory = /usr/local/man
    mydestination = example.com, localhost.com, localhost
    mydomain = example.com
    myhostname = example.com
    mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
    mynetworks_style = host
    myorigin = $mydomain
    newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
    queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
    readme_directory = no
    recipient_delimiter = +
    relay_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf
    relayhost =
    setgid_group = mwdpdrop
    smtp_tls_security_level = may
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
    smtp_use_tls = yes
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
    smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl
    smtpd_delay_reject = yes
    smtpd_helo_required = yes
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
    smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
    smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
    smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/controlled_envelope_senders
    smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_sender_domain, permit_mynetworks
    smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
    smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
    smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
    smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
    smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
    smtpd_tls_security_level = may
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
    smtpd_use_tls = yes
    tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
    virtual_alias_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_alias_map.cf
    virtual_gid_maps = static:3205
    virtual_mailbox_base = /mwdmail/mbox
    virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_domain_map.cf
    virtual_mailbox_limit = 512000000
    virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_map.cf
    virtual_minimum_uid = 3205
    virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
    virtual_uid_maps = static:3205
```

### postconf -M (master.cf file)

```
#SMTP on port 25, unencrypted.
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v

smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v

# SMTP with TLS on port 587.
submission inet n - - - - smtpd -v
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/controlled_envelope_senders
# -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

# SMTP over SSL on port 465.
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous

#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache

# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=mwdvm:mwdvm argv=/usr/bin/vendor_perl/spamc -f -e /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

# The next two entries integrate with Amavis for anti-virus/spam checks.
amavis      unix    -       -       -       -       3       smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o max_use=20
127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o local_recipient_maps=
  -o relay_recipient_maps=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
 -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
  -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
  -o mynetworks=192.168.1.0/32,127.0.0.0/8
#  -o mynetworks=0.0.0.0
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
#
#
##############
# Integration with Dovecot - hand mail over to it for local delivery, and
# run the process under the vmail user and mail group.
dovecot      unix   -        n      n       -       -   pipe
  flags=DRhu user=mwdvm:mwdvm argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $(recipient)
```

SASL AUTHENTICATION is enabled per telnet check

```
root@example:~# telnet 192.168.1.11 25
Trying 192.168.1.11...
Connected to 192.168.1.11.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 example.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo example.com
250-example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

### doveconf -n

```
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.13.0-29-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
first_valid_uid = 3205
last_valid_uid = 3205
mail_gid = mwdvm
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_uid = mwdvm
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@example.com
protocols = imap pop3 sieve
service auth-worker {
  user = $default_internal_user
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = mwdpost
    mode = 0660
    user = mwdpost
  }
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
    #group = postfix
    group = mwdpost
    mode = 0660
    #user = postfix
    user = mwdpost
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = mwdvm
    mode = 0600
    user = mwdvm
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = mwdpost
    mode = 0600
    user = mwdpost
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}
protocol lda {
  auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  log_path = /var/log/dovecot-lda.log
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster
  quota_full_tempfail = yes
  rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r
}
```

dovecot authentication file:

```
# This file is opened as root, so it should be owned by root and mode 0600.
#
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL
#
# For the sql passdb module, you'll need a database with a table that
# contains fields for at least the username and password. If you want to
# use the user@domain syntax, you might want to have a separate domain
# field as well.
#
# If your users all have the same uig/gid, and have predictable home
# directories, you can use the static userdb module to generate the home
# dir based on the username and domain. In this case, you won't need fields
# for home, uid, or gid in the database.
#
# If you prefer to use the sql userdb module, you'll want to add fields
# for home, uid, and gid. Here is an example table:
#
# CREATE TABLE users (
#     username VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
#     domain VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
#     password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
#     home VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
#     uid INTEGER NOT NULL,
#     gid INTEGER NOT NULL,
#     active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL
# );

# Database driver: mysql, pgsql, sqlite
#driver = 
driver = pgsql

# Database connection string. This is driver-specific setting.
#
# HA / round-robin load-balancing is supported by giving multiple host
# settings, like: host=sql1.host.org host=sql2.host.org
#
# pgsql:
#   For available options, see the PostgreSQL documention for the
#   PQconnectdb function of libpq.
#   Use maxconns=n (default 5) to change how many connections Dovecot can
#   create to pgsql.
#
# mysql:
#   Basic options emulate PostgreSQL option names:
#     host, port, user, password, dbname
#
#   But also adds some new settings:
#     client_flags        - See MySQL manual
#     ssl_ca, ssl_ca_path - Set either one or both to enable SSL
#     ssl_cert, ssl_key   - For sending client-side certificates to server
#     ssl_cipher          - Set minimum allowed cipher security (default: HIGH)
#     option_file         - Read options from the given file instead of
#                           the default my.cnf location
#     option_group        - Read options from the given group (default: client)
# 
#   You can connect to UNIX sockets by using host: host=/var/run/mysql.sock
#   Note that currently you can't use spaces in parameters.
#
# sqlite:
#   The path to the database file.
#
# Examples:
#   connect = host=192.168.1.1 dbname=users
#   connect = host=sql.example.com dbname=virtual user=virtual password=blarg
#   connect = /etc/dovecot/authdb.sqlite
#
#connect =
connect = host=192.168.1.11:3145 dbname=mwdmail user=mwdmlusr password=t1mim@1l

# Default password scheme.
#
# List of supported schemes is in
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes
#
#default_pass_scheme = MD5
default_pass_scheme = SHA516-CRYPT


# passdb query to retrieve the password. It can return fields:
#   password - The user's password. This field must be returned.
#   user - user@domain from the database. Needed with case-insensitive lookups.
#   username and domain - An alternative way to represent the "user" field.
#
# The "user" field is often necessary with case-insensitive lookups to avoid
# e.g. "name" and "nAme" logins creating two different mail directories. If
# your user and domain names are in separate fields, you can return "username"
# and "domain" fields instead of "user".
#
# The query can also return other fields which have a special meaning, see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields
#
# Commonly used available substitutions (see http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Variables
# for full list):
#   %u = entire user@domain
#   %n = user part of user@domain
#   %d = domain part of user@domain
# 
# Note that these can be used only as input to SQL query. If the query outputs
# any of these substitutions, they're not touched. Otherwise it would be
# difficult to have eg. usernames containing '%' characters.
#
# Example:
#   password_query = SELECT userid AS user, pw AS password \
#     FROM users WHERE userid = '%u' AND active = 'Y'
#
#password_query = \
#  SELECT username, domain, password \
#  FROM users WHERE username = '%n' AND domain = '%d'
password_query = \
SELECT username as user, password, '/mwdmail/mbox/%d/%n' as userdb_home, 'maildir:/mwdmail/mbox/%d/%n' as userdb_mail, 3205 as userdb_uid, 3205 as userdb_gid \
FROM mailbox WHERE username='%u' AND active = true;

# userdb query to retrieve the user information. It can return fields:
#   uid - System UID (overrides mail_uid setting)
#   gid - System GID (overrides mail_gid setting)
#   home - Home directory
#   mail - Mail location (overrides mail_location setting)
#
# None of these are strictly required. If you use a single UID and GID, and
# home or mail directory fits to a template string, you could use userdb static
# instead. For a list of all fields that can be returned, see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/UserDatabase/ExtraFields
#
# Examples:
#   user_query = SELECT home, uid, gid FROM users WHERE userid = '%u'
#   user_query = SELECT dir AS home, user AS uid, group AS gid FROM users where userid = '%u'
#   user_query = SELECT home, 501 AS uid, 501 AS gid FROM users WHERE userid = '%u'
#
#user_query = \
#  SELECT home, uid, gid \
#  FROM users WHERE username = '%n' AND domain = '%d'
user_query = \
SELECT '/mwdmail/mbox/%d/%n' as home, 'maildir:/mwdmail/mbox/%d/%n' as mail, 3205 AS uid, 3205 AS gid, 'dirsize:storage=' ||  quota AS quota FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = true


# If you wish to avoid two SQL lookups (passdb + userdb), you can use
# userdb prefetch instead of userdb sql in dovecot.conf. In that case you'll
# also have to return userdb fields in password_query prefixed with "userdb_"
# string. For example:
#password_query = \
#  SELECT userid AS user, password, \
#    home AS userdb_home, uid AS userdb_uid, gid AS userdb_gid \
#  FROM users WHERE userid = '%u'

# Query to get a list of all usernames.
#iterate_query = SELECT username AS user FROM users
```

I **can do** the following:

- send email to external address from commandline root account
- Send email to local and virtual mailboxes from commandline root account
- Receive email to a virtual mailbox from external email accounts *

I can **NOT** do the following:

- Receive email to a virtual mailbox from external email accounts (*THIS IS FIXED)
- Log into a virtual mailbox from a remote client like thunderbird or roundcube

I know there must be some configuration I missing or mixing up.  Please help. Thanks

*** **UPDATED** *** 6/13/2014 *******
Per @clement, I updated the post with the files and while doing dovecot -n. I noticed I had the wrong userid/groupid in file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/99-mail-stack-delivery.conf.ext corrected it and then the error went away .  I also can receive email from external accounts, but I get a new error and when I try to connect through thunderbird or roundcube the same error (posted above appears)

### New error (from syslog)

```
Jun 13 12:48:59 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) Connecting to SQL database server
Jun 13 12:48:59 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) connect_to_sql: 'DBI:Pg:database=mwdmail;host=192.168.1.11;port=3145' succeeded
Jun 13 12:48:59 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) ESMTP::10024 /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20140613T124859-01636-8zgfTr8G: <myemailid@gmail.com> -> <cmadm@example.com> SIZE=1994 Received: from example.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (example.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP for <cmadm@example.com>; Fri, 13 Jun 2014 12:48:59 -0400 (EDT)
Jun 13 12:48:59 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) body hash: 3c1b1ba2edc70e49703dfd1f314cbf88
Jun 13 12:48:59 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) dkim: FAILED Author+Sender+MailFrom signature by d=gmail.com, From: <myemailid@gmail.com>, a=rsa-sha256, c=relaxed/relaxed, s=20120113, i=@gmail.com, fail (message has been altered)
Jun 13 12:48:59 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) Checking: ir664hlqxaJx [209.85.128.170] <myemailid@gmail.com> -> <cmadm@example.com>
Jun 13 12:48:59 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) 2822.From: <myemailid@gmail.com>
Jun 13 12:48:59 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) p001 1 Content-Type: text/plain, size: 769 B, name:
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) Checking for banned types and filenames
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) collect banned table[0]: cmadm@example.com, tables: DEFAULT=>Amavis::Lookup::RE=ARRAY(0x2541dc0)
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) p.path cmadm@example.com: "P=p001,L=1,M=text/plain,T=asc"
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) run_av Using (ClamAV-clamd): (code) CONTSCAN /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20140613T124859-01636-8zgfTr8G/parts\n
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) ClamAV-clamd: Connecting to socket  /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) new socket by IO::Socket::UNIX to /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl, timeout 10
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) ClamAV-clamd: Sending CONTSCAN /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20140613T124859-01636-8zgfTr8G/parts\n to socket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) rw_loop read: got eof
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) run_av (ClamAV-clamd): CLEAN
Jun 13 12:49:00 example amavis[1636]: (01636-01) run_av (ClamAV-clamd) result: clean
```

Comment: Please post the `doveconf -n` output and the file holding DB connectivity info for authentication in dovecot.

Comment: Thanks @clement .  I made the updates in the post above. I fixed an error that prevented me from received external emails, but there is a new error, posted above, and the  same error reappears when I try to connect to the mail server from Thunderbird or Roundcube.  Must be something wrong in my dovecot and/or SASL config file?

Comment: If logging into your email accounts from email client is the issue, then look for dovecot log lines in your maillog. The above logs are generated by amavis and they are not relevant for this problem.

Comment: Thanks @clement but I don't know how to resolve the issue "auth: Error: pgsql(192.168.1.11:3145): Connect failed to database mwdmail: could not translate host name "192.168.1.11:3145" to address: Name or service not known".  It seems like it can't resolve the host name(which is actually an ip address).  Should I switch to using "localhost:3145"...Google search are not helpful :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@clement ..this is resolved.  I reinstalled everything again and carefully updated all my postfix and dovecot files.  I had a few typos and the new User ID and Group ID I created for postfix and postdrop did not have the correct permissions everywhere.  I have another issue but will report that on another post.

Thank you.