# Why can't I get a telnet localhost 25, ehlo localhost output of 250-AUTH?

Tags: server, email, postfix, dovecot

How do I get a telnet localhost 25 output of 250-AUTH LOGIN?  Similar to the questions asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482223/postfix-postgresql-dovecot-sasl-authentication-fails-ubuntu-14-04lts-server?lq=1)  and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411057/postfix-dovecot-sasl-authentication-not-enabled-working-ubuntu-12-04-server), I set up a Postfix-Dovecot mail server using Ubuntu 12.04LTS and can not get it to authenticate.

When `smtp_tls_auth_only = no` ([as recommended here](https://askubuntu.com/a/411075/178112)), my connection closes:

```
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

When `smtp_tls_auth_only = yes`, here's what I get:

```
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-mydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

Below is the output from their respective bash prompt commands (shown in bold):

```
**postconf -m**
/etc/postfix$ postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
internal
memcache
nis
proxy
regexp
sdbm
sqlite
static
tcp
texthash
unix

**postconf -a**
cyrus
dovecot

**postconf -n** 
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/readme
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550


**postconf -M** 

smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtpd      pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot -o smtpd_sasl_path=/var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtps      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_non_fqdn_recipient,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
pickup     fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Persistent failures appear in the **/var/log/mail.log** output such as:

```
Nov 25 09:38:07 mail postfix/master[1131]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Nov 25 09:42:00 mail postfix/master[1131]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Nov 25 09:42:11 mail postfix/smtpd[16030]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
Nov 25 09:42:11 mail postfix/smtpd[16030]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 09:42:41 mail postfix/smtpd[16030]: lost connection after EHLO from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 09:42:41 mail postfix/smtpd[16030]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 09:43:45 mail postfix/master[1131]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Nov 25 09:43:51 mail postfix/smtpd[16067]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
Nov 25 09:43:51 mail postfix/smtpd[16067]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 09:43:51 mail postfix/smtpd[16067]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Nov 25 09:43:51 mail postfix/smtpd[16067]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Nov 25 09:43:52 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 16067 exit status 1
Nov 25 09:43:52 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Nov 25 09:46:25 mail postfix/smtpd[16082]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
Nov 25 09:46:25 mail postfix/smtpd[16082]: connect from mail134-3.atl141.mandrillapp.com[198.2.134.3]
Nov 25 09:46:25 mail postfix/smtpd[16082]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Nov 25 09:46:25 mail postfix/smtpd[16082]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Nov 25 09:46:26 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 16082 exit status 1
Nov 25 09:46:26 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Nov 25 09:48:06 mail postfix/anvil[16084]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:198.2.134.3) at Nov 25 09:46:25
Nov 25 09:48:06 mail postfix/anvil[16084]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:198.2.134.3) at Nov 25 09:46:25
Nov 25 09:48:06 mail postfix/anvil[16084]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Nov 25 09:46:25
Nov 25 09:59:40 mail postfix/smtpd[16167]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
Nov 25 09:59:40 mail postfix/smtpd[16167]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 09:59:40 mail postfix/smtpd[16167]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Nov 25 09:59:40 mail postfix/smtpd[16167]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Nov 25 09:59:41 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 16167 exit status 1
Nov 25 09:59:41 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Nov 25 10:00:48 mail postfix/smtpd[16177]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
Nov 25 10:00:48 mail postfix/smtpd[16177]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 10:01:26 mail postfix/smtpd[16181]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
Nov 25 10:01:26 mail postfix/smtpd[16181]: connect from mail134-3.atl141.mandrillapp.com[198.2.134.3]
Nov 25 10:01:26 mail postfix/smtpd[16181]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Nov 25 10:01:26 mail postfix/smtpd[16181]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Nov 25 10:01:27 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 16181 exit status 1
Nov 25 10:01:27 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Nov 25 10:03:07 mail postfix/anvil[16182]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:198.2.134.3) at Nov 25 10:01:26
Nov 25 10:03:07 mail postfix/anvil[16182]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:198.2.134.3) at Nov 25 10:01:26
Nov 25 10:03:07 mail postfix/anvil[16182]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Nov 25 10:01:26
Nov 25 10:05:54 mail postfix/smtpd[16177]: timeout after EHLO from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 10:05:54 mail postfix/smtpd[16177]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 10:16:27 mail postfix/smtpd[16502]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
Nov 25 10:16:27 mail postfix/smtpd[16502]: connect from mail134-3.atl141.mandrillapp.com[198.2.134.3]
Nov 25 10:16:27 mail postfix/smtpd[16502]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Nov 25 10:16:27 mail postfix/smtpd[16502]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Nov 25 10:16:28 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 16502 exit status 1
Nov 25 10:16:28 mail postfix/master[1131]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Nov 25 10:18:08 mail postfix/anvil[16504]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:198.2.134.3) at Nov 25 10:16:27
Nov 25 10:18:08 mail postfix/anvil[16504]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:198.2.134.3) at Nov 25 10:16:27
Nov 25 10:18:08 mail postfix/anvil[16504]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Nov 25 10:16:27
```

Note that depending on how I set the alias_maps flag e.g. from the default hash:/etc/postix to the optional (see www.postfix.org/pgsql_table.5.html) alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/pgsql-aliases.cf, I get different output but still cannot get past some of the consistent failures related to private/auth or /var/spool/postfix/private/auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

Everything is actually in your logs:

```
Nov 25 09:42:11 mail postfix/smtpd[16030]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
```

Your postfix doesn't recognize pgsql dictionary type (as you can see yourself it's not on your list)
You have to install the following package:

`postfix-pgsql` - PostgreSQL map support for Postfix

Second thing is SASL:

```
Nov 25 09:46:25 mail postfix/smtpd[16082]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Nov 25 09:46:25 mail postfix/smtpd[16082]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

Just having a quick look at your configuration.
Something is misconfigured and dovecot - which, as I see, you want to use for sasl - can't access private/auth. I would check file permissions as the first thing.

Fix those two issues and let's see if there's anything more.

Comment: Yes, I was missing postfix-pgsql (now installed). And yes, also had a permission error message:  doveadm(christophe):  connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb) failed: Permission denied (euid=1000(christophe) egid=1000(christophe) missing +r perm: /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
doveadm(christophe): Fatal: User lookup failed: Internal error occurred.  Made changes. Now I have new errors to track down: mail dovecot: auth: Error: FATAL:  password authentication  failed for user "mailreader"; mail postfix/smtpd[3147]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms; etc.

Comment: Have you checked also permissions on /var/spool/postfix/private/auth? Is dovecot in postfix group, so dovecot is allowed to read private/auth?

Answer (score 1):

Something common is /etc/postfix/main.cf errors.
Especially lines:

```
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_sasl_local_domain ='
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous'
sudo postconf -e 'broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination'
sudo postconf -e 'inet_interfaces = all'
```

One of my very first times , I misstyped smtpd_recipient_restrictions and I was looking for the problem for 3 dayz.

PS:In the same file , smtpd_tls , options are also likely to cause this kind of problems.