# my mailserver is not responding when I send a ehlo localhost

Tags: 16.04, mail-server

I tried to make a mailserver with [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix)

I work with Ubuntu Server 16.04

Executing the testing part doesn't provide any respond from my local mailserver (when I send a `ehlo localhost` message).

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: please take a look at this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553664/why-cant-i-get-a-telnet-localhost-25-ehlo-localhost-output-of-250-auth) for two reasons: 1) You might find an answer for your problem. 2) Please see the format of the question with the details provided, and [edit] your question to holds those data, which are required if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks, this one is solved. I had a typo in the configuration.